# If I setcontentview in Cordova Plugin, how do I set content view back to cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, setcontentview

I am creating a Cordova Android plugin to perform authentication (with Oracle Mobile and Social SDK). When I kick off the authentication method I need to setContentView a view provided by Oracle. Here is how the code looks like:

```
            View myview = mss.authenticate();
            cordova.getActivity().setContentView(myview);
```

This is working fine. The Oracle's authentication screen comes up and I can enter my credentials. But when I am done I don't know how to switch back to the Cordova view (back to my index.html). I am able to set callback context status correctly and able to send back message to JavaScript which can throw an alert. However the screen is stuck at the authentication screen. I would like to go back to the index.html page.

Any guidance on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: any progress? I am also very curious about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a function from the cordova-plugin-splashscreen repo at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/src/android/SplashScreen.java

```
private View getView() {
    try {
        return (View)webView.getClass().getMethod("getView").invoke(webView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return (View)webView;
    }
}
```

To go back to the Cordova web view you can then do:

```
cordova.getActivity().setContentView(getView());
```